# Typescript lint doesn't recognize type transform decorator

Tags: typescript, nestjs, lint, class-validator

I'm using nestjs with class validator to validate env variables, `configuration.service.ts` is getting its values from configService file which get what it needs from .env and put it in a json object.

In the port and timeout properties I expect to receive a string since it came from a .env file, the decorator `@Type(() => Number)` will try to convert whatever it receives into a Number. As far I'm concerned, the decorator only runs as the function call ends, so the function takes a string and returns a string and after that the string is casted into a Number.

The problem is the properties port and connectTimeoutMS expects a Number, the typescript lint claims it's receiving a string, looks like it's not recognizing the cast decorator.
I want to know whether there's a way to get around this or I have to drop the cast decorator.

configuration.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import {
    IsBoolean,
    IsDefined,
    IsInt,
    IsNumber,
    IsString,
} from 'class-validator';
import { ValidatedConfigService } from 'src/config/utils/validate.config';
import { DatabaseType, Logger } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseConfigService extends ValidatedConfigService {
    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
        super();
    }

    @IsString()
    @IsDefined()
    get type(): DatabaseType {
        return this.configService.get<DatabaseType>('database.type');
    }

    @IsString()
    @IsDefined()
    get host(): string {
        return this.configService.get<string>('database.host');
    }

    @IsInt()   
    @IsDefined()
    @Type(() => Number)
    get port(): string {
        return this.configService.get<string>('database.port');
    }
    
    @IsNumber()   
    @IsDefined()
    @Type(() => Number)
    get timeOut(): string {
        return (
            this.configService.get<string>('database.connectTimeoutMS') ||
            '2000'
        );
    }

    @IsString()
    @IsDefined()
    get entities(): string {
        return this.configService.get<string>('database.entities');
    }

  
}
```

database.configuration.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';
import { DatabaseConfigService } from './configuration.service';

export class DatabaseConfigController {
    constructor(private readonly configService: DatabaseConfigService) {}

    get settings(): ConnectionOptions {
        return {
            type: this.configService.type,
            host: this.configService.host,
            port: this.configService.port,
            connectTimeoutMS: this.configService.timeOut,
            entities: [this.configService.entities],           
        };
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,    
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

**[Edit 12/20/21]**

I had to give up from using the `@Type()` decorator, as Micael Levi stated in his answer, this line is explicitly telling to TSC to expect a string `get timeOut(): string`.

So I have to change it to number, but doing that I also need to change the type I am returning inside the function to either any or casting it to a number.

This way gives an obvious type error.

```
    @IsInt()
    @IsDefined()
    get port(): number {       
        return this.configService.get<string>('db.port');
    }
```

Not specifying the type will not trigger the lint but at runtime will throw an error due to the `IsInt()` decorator because it's getting a string from `database.configuration.ts`

```
    @IsInt()
    @IsDefined()
    get port(): number {       
        return this.configService.get('db.port');
    }
```

The solution is casting it to a number by hand, this casting process also can be done in `database.configuration.ts`.

```
    @IsInt()
    @IsDefined()
    get port(): number {       
        return parseInt(this.configService.get<string>('db.port'), 10);
    }
```

Maybe I was using the `@Type()` decorator in a way that it is not intended to be used, tbh I never needed to use it, I just wanted to do all validations using this package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line **you're** (not TS) telling to TSC that `this.configService.timeOut` is an `string`

```
get timeOut(): string
```

just change it to `get timeOut(): number`. Decorators won't type anything for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, too bad the @type decorator doesn't work the way I want.

Comment: the `@Type()` is just to explicity mark the returning type (as a value) of that property. So then `class-validator` can understand it properly. I'm pretty sure you don't need them for your case btw.